# Passing data between players through a central server/database

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

**Current State:**

I have a multiplayer based game in Unity written in C#.

**State to achieve:**

I need the game to connect to the server. I later need it to send the data to the server of player's behavior, and receive the data from the other players through the server. I can do most of the PHP scripting, but I'm very new to C#. I just need help connecting the client to the server.

I have tried to research but do not know how to begin. May anyone guide me please?

Comment: Simple, build a PHP api and process your data there using a combination between post and get; then work on finding a way to send http requests from C# which i'm 99.99% is possible.

Comment: @AaronNoHuanKnows Thank you. I'll see what I can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey its pretty very simple to do it. Since you are already familiar with php programming, I will show you how to connect Unity to Server through your PHP scripts.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.IO;

public class ConnectToServer : MonoBehaviour
{
 
 string InsertURL = "http://localhost/InsertData.php"; //Add your php script here
 public int valueToEnter = 2; //Create public variables that represent your data in Database/php
 
   public void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SendToServer());
    }

    IEnumerator SendToServer()
    {

        WWWForm liveForm = new WWWForm();
        liveForm.AddField("valueToEnterPost", valueToEnter ); //Reference your php variable name
        WWW wwwLive = new WWW(InsertURL, liveForm);

        yield return null;
        StartCoroutine(RetrieveFromServer());

       
    }

    IEnumerator RetreiveFromServer()
    {
      //Below bit of code is to retrieve the data from server

        string dataExtract;
        WWW dataAfterExtract = new WWW("http://localhost/GetData.php"); //You might have php script to retrieve data from server
        yield return dataAfterExtract ;
        dataExtract = dataAfterExtract.text;
     }
```

You will find Docs from here https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html

Comment: I have one question though: When getting data from the server, would it return the contents of the page. If so, I could just use the PHP `echo()` function to return data, right?